# Access to files in Sharepoint 2007 using javascript from external site

Tags: java, javascript, file, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I want to get access to download files from SharePoint 2007 (different Libraries) using javascript or java. So i want to code application which will allow to download files from SharePoint 2007. I have a full access to SharePoint. Can i do it? If i can, reference me please to some libraries or tools to do it. I have not experience with SharePoint at all.

Actually i want to code application which can give access to all information which contains in SharePoint: files, lists and etc.

Update:

I did not ask you to find library or something. I ask you: "Can i do it?". Is there technically possibility. Because i did not find some thing useful after googling and have no experience with SharePoint.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254394/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: update question to explain what i want exactly

Comment: I suppose you didn't google "sharepoint 2007 api" then :/

Comment: "Can i do it? If i can, reference me please to some **libraries or tools** to do it" makes it offtopic.

Comment: You didn't google "sharepoint java" either :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [java-sharepoint-library](https://code.google.com/p/java-sharepoint-library/):

"If you want connect your java application to SharePoint through web services this project is what you are looking for. API of the library is similar like Sharepoint API. It means that you do not have to know nothing about Sharepoint web services and NTLM authentication. You can create objects like SPsite, SPWeb, SPList, etc. and you can browse Sharepoint through these SPobjects."

From [Java Tip: Consuming SharePoint web services with a Java client](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078906/enterprise-java/java-tip-consuming-sharepoint-web-services-with-a-java-client.html):

"In this Java tip I'll show you how to perform basic CRUD operations on a SharePoint document folder from a Java client. The demonstration will focus on some of the more popular methods that any SharePoint web service consumer is likely to invoke, which are found in Microsoft's Copy and Lists services. For the CRUD operations we'll use CAML (Collaborative Application Markup Language), an XML-based language utilized in many of the methods exposed by Copy and Lists. You'll learn how to construct valid CAML structures that are passed as method parameters or assigned to object properties, which are in turn passed as parameters to these services. "